# Differentiating methods from variables of an object

Tags: python

Given an object `myObject`, I do

```
print dir(myObject)
```

This will dump variable and method names. How can I distinguish which are variables, and which are methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recognize methods using `types.MethodType`:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.x = 2
   ...:     def f(self):
   ...:         return 1

In [2]: a=A()

In [3]: import types

In [4]: isinstance(a.f, types.MethodType)
Out[4]: True
```

Note: Static methods are of type `types.FunctionType`.

**Update**: So to get all the function names, you can do

```
In [5]: [name for name in dir(a) if isinstance(getattr(a, name), types.MethodType)]
Out[5]: ['__init__', 'f']
```

Comment: Note that the default `__init__`, `__str__`, `__reduce__` etc. are also of type `types.FunctionType`.

Answer (score 2):

@JanPöschko's answer is correct, but won't catch all methods. Depending on the use case, the best way to check for a method may be good old `callable`.

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     pass
>>> [member for member in dir(Foo()) if callable(getattr(Foo(), member))]
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

This also catches class and static methods.

Comment: Too inclusive? This also catches members that contain functions (or other callables), but that are not methods in the sense of getting the object as an implicit first argument.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: those would be static methods. I covered that below the code example.

Comment: Or any other variable to which you have assigned a function as the value, i.e., potentially any object attribute.

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber: I understand, but such a member would automatically behave as a static method. In fact, I don't think there's any way to distinguish it from one created with `@staticmethod`.

Comment: I agree, there's not much (or any? I'm not sure) difference between static methods and members with functions as values. Nonetheless, their use cases tend to be quite different and one should be aware that your approach can capture more -- maybe a *lot* more -- than just what appears as a method in the class definition. Basically, I'm just trying to unpack your "depending on the use case" a little.